# Can wires length really increase surge voltage?

Tags: electromagnetism

Does this have basis in reality or just an urban legend that longer wire length can increase surge voltage bec of lenz law and stuff?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But the induced voltages are very small except at very high frequency currents. The self-inductance of a straight wire involves a complex formula. I found one in the following link (but caution you I have not validated it) that is a function of the length the wire.

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/wire-self-inductance-calculator/

Given the inductance for a given length of wire, the induced voltage along the length is given by:

$$v=L\frac{di}{dt}$$

So the greater the rate of change in current, the greater the induced voltage.

The 8/20 μs current wave shown in the caption is a standard current pulse used to evaluate the ability of surge protective devices (SPD) to suppress transients.  It involves a current pulse with a rise time of 8 μs rise time and 20 μs decay. I believe it is an IEEE specification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So when lightning hits the lines. The voltage would further increases the longer are the wires??

Comment: Lightning currents are extremely high. Forgetting the inductance of the wire for a moment, even the lightning current times the ohmic resistance of a wire results in a high voltage across the wire. The longer the wire, the higher the ohmic resistance and the higher the voltage across the wire. The effect of the inductance of the wire on the voltage is due to the rate of change in current, not the magnitude. But the two add together.

Comment: Is it true that the inductance of the air is similar to the inductance of the wire? Hence some EE reason the wire doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Jtl Where did you hear that the inductance of air is similar to the inductance of the wire?

Comment: check this out... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/409480/voltage-inductance-lightning-in-a-length-of-wire  what do you think? what would happen if the inductance of air is similar to the inductance of the wire?

Comment: Now I see you got the idea from an Andy aka answer to a question of yours on the electrical engineering stack exchange. But when you make the statement that “inductance of the air is similar to the inductance of the wire” you are making it out of the context of the Andy aka answer. Inductance is a property of a conductor. Normally, air is an excellent insulator. So inductance does not normally apply to air.

Comment: But the high voltage of a lightning strike breaks air down and it becomes a conductor. Only then can one speak of the inductance of air. In any case, I don’t think it is relevant to a discussion of induced voltages in building wiring and the surge protective devices (SPDs) that are used in a building.

Comment: Low-voltage (less than 1000 v) SPDs that are used in buildings do not protect equipment against direct lightning strikes. They are the downstream protection component of a multiple component protection scheme against the effects of lightning. They are intended to protect electrical power and telecommunications equipment in the building against overvoltage, which may include but are not limited to, lightning induced overvoltage in the building.

Comment: These overvoltages can occur as a consequence of direct lightning strikes on overhead power and telephone lines outside the building resulting in induced transient currents traveling into the building wiring system.

Comment: You said when lightning strike broke air down and it became a conductor. But why is it not relevant to a discussion of induced voltages in building wiring and SPDs used in building? But still the inductance of air broken down by lightning and inductance of wire is really the same?

Comment: The air that breaks down due to the lightning strike is outside the building not inside the building. The only breakdown of air within the building would be  electrical spacings subjected to induced overvoltage. SPDs are intended suppress overvoltage before that happens.

Comment: So what is the inductance of broken down air (by lightning) really? And what is the inductance of wire? You know the approximate values?

Comment: @Jtl I'm afraid this discussion is going nowhere. Good luck in finding the answer you want.

Comment: You asked me where I hear that the inductance of air is similar to the inductance of the wire? I gave you the source. You reasoned they were not connected because one is outside the building. No problem. So I'm just verifying if you agree the approximate values of capacitance of air and wire is similar. Maybe I should make a new post just to ask this question.

Comment: Make a new post